# Day Late on Delivery of Bill to Verizon

Tags: billing

I'm pretty new to the adult world, I just paid my 7th Verizon bill, but I submitted the payment online. The bill asked for payment due by a Monday, and the earliest the bank can deliver the check is on the day after, the Tuesday.

Is this going to be a problem at all?

Comment: If it does become a problem (e.g. Verizon considers it 'late', charges you a fee and probably dings your credit score), it may be worth a call to VZ customer service to apologize and see if they'll waive the fee - worked for me once before when a (small) bill went unnoticed on a new credit card account...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not. Generally its not a good idea to wait for the last moment, because there's always something unexpected that can happen.

You can also use "direct pay" (or whatever they call it on Verizon) to pay instead of the banks' bill-pay feature, so that the payment is originated by Verizon (or whatever else service provider), and not the bank. This way it will be posted earlier.

Comment: +1 Agree.  Also, if one is worried about the bill being a day late, a pre-emptive call to customer service might help.  Just explain yourself and show that you are proactive.

Comment: +1 One advantage of automated payments originated by Verizon (or other similar utility or credit card company) is that the payment is on time. It doesn't post earlier; it usually posts _to the Verizon account_ on the date due, and may be paid by the _customer's bank_ the same day or maybe even a day or two later. On the other hand, some people do have a rooted aversion to letting utilities generate the automated payment requests. Thus, generating an auto-pay oneself a day or two in advance is a very good idea, unless cash flow is a problem... The interest lost by paying a day early is picayune